# Trying to Get Array of Tables and Databases in Smarty

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I Have an array of Databases and Tables from MySQL. I Can't Seem to Get a List of Tables under each database in Smarty? I Have tried multiple foreach statements and none seem to work. The Database Name shows correct but the tables do not. I appreciate all of the help.

My PHP:

```
$conn = connect();

$db_sql = $conn->query("SHOW DATABASES;");
$dbs = array();
while ($db = $db_sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
{
    $db_name = $db[0];
    $dbs[] = $db_name;
}

$tables = array();
foreach ($dbs as $db => $value) {
    $table_sql = $conn->query("SHOW TABLES FROM $value");
    while ($table_ = $table_sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
    {
        $tb_name = $table_[0];
        $tables[$value]['Tables'][] = $tb_name;
    }
}

$smarty->assign("dbs", $tables);
```

My Smarty:

```
 {foreach from=$dbs key=db item=value}
                    <li>
                        <a class="tree-toggler nav-header" href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span> {$db}</a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                        {foreach from=$value->Tables  item=$table}
                            <li><a href="#">{$table}</a></li>
                        {/foreach}
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                {/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your smarty code in the second foreach loop

Replace

This line of your code - {foreach from=$value->Tables  item=$table}
WITH
This line - {foreach from=$value.Tables item=table}

And it will be working